# Как обойти ошибку "WinSock.h has already been included" при сборке OSRM в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, boost

Я только начал делать форк этой библиотеки и уже столкнулся с ошибкой конфликта файлов WinSock.h и включенной в boost WinSock2.h. Определение константы `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` перед `include <windows.h>` не решило проблему. Возможно, мне ее следует определить в другом месте.

Comment: Просто `include <windows.h>` в таком случае не надо, WinSock сам подключает этот заголовок.

Comment: Я удалил, ничего не изменилось. Возможно, windows.h используется другими зависимостями.

Answer (score 1):

Если такие сложности возникают при сборке MSVS, то попробуйте Mingw - авось, будет проще.